# pyparsing operatorprecedence to parse empty query

Tags: python, pyparsing, operator-precedence

I am using pyparsing.operatorprecedence to parse infix notation query. The code is

```
 filterExpr = pp.quotedString.setParseAction(pp.removeQuotes) |\
                 pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars="()")

searchTerm = (~and_ + ~or_ + ~not_) + filterExpr

searchExpr = pp.operatorPrecedence(
                searchTerm,
                [
                (not_, 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, SearchNotOperation),
                (pp.Optional(and_, default="AND"), 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, SearchAndOperation),
                (or_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, SearchOrOperation),
                ])
```

This parses expressions like '(foo bar) or baz', but fails on edge case, where empty string or empty brackets '()' are provided.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: With operatorPrecedence, an empty string or empty brackets is not valid, you have to have at least one searchTerm somewhere. You *might* try changing the operand passed to operatorPrecedence to `Optional(searchTerm)`, but this seems dicey to me.

Comment: The way I've 'fixed' this is to check if the string to parse contains a whitespace. If it does, then parse it, else there is no need to do it. Of course this only works if you use words as operands since they need to be surrounded with whitespaces.